# Loading more than URL in The same browser using jxbrowser

Tags: url, jxbrowser

I'am using jxbrowser,

This code loads one URL in one browser and saves  it's page .

```
public class JxBrowserDemo {
public JxBrowserDemo(String url) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
         browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
             @Override
             public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
                 if (event.isMainFrame()){
                      String filePath = "G:\\Test\\index"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".html";
                      String dirPath = "G:\\Test\\resources";
                      event.getBrowser().saveWebPage(filePath, dirPath, SavePageType.COMPLETE_HTML);
                 }
             }
         });

        browser.loadURL(url);
        if(!browser.isLoading())
        {
            browser.dispose();
        }
    }

public static void main(String args[])
{

JxBrowserDemo jxBrowserDemo=new JxBrowserDemo("www.google.com");

}

}
```

could I load more than URL in the same browser and save it's pages in Local Path ?

Thanks In advance ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load one by one as many URLs as you want and save these web pages by the `saveWebPage()` method in the same browser.
You should completely load the web page, invoke the `saveWebPage()` method, wait until the web page is saved, and then repeat these actions with the next URL.
The `dispose()` method should be invoked when you don't need to perform any actions with this browser instance.

Comment: please how to wait until web page is saved

Comment: You should track the filePath and dirPath exsistence on your file system. Once these files appear you can start loading the next URL with the browser instance.